# Is there a migration tool for upgrading a team project process template to CMMI 5.0 from 4.2

Tags: tfs, cmmi

We have lots of team projects at our company which are using CMMI 4.2 process template. I'm going to upgrade to CMMI 5.0 or maybe CMMI 6.0.

I've found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms194914%28v=VS.80%29.aspx which describes some solutions, but they seems tricky instead of official!

Worth to mention that I'm NOT going to change the process template (eg. Agile to CMMI), I just want to upgrade to the newer version, so is there any easy to use migration tool to upgrade a team project process template to CMMI 5.0 (from 4.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no canned solution for doing this, and it also depends on how customized the process templates have been made for the different team projects (the less customization, the easier!). As of now, the only way to upgrade, or change, process templates is manual. Martin Hinshelwood has a blog on upgrading/migrating your process templates here: http://nakedalm.com/do-you-know-how-to-upgrade-a-process-template-but-still-keep-your-data-intact/. I would recommend you follow #7 in the blog for what exactly you are trying to achieve.